# Tick marks and Axis on barplot plotnine/python

Tags: python, ggplot2, plotnine

I am creating some bar plots using plotnine library for the first time. However, I have two issues with the axis/tick marks:

1. It seems the tick marks are not evenly spaced in the graphs (see fig) which makes them inaccurate. What might be happening here ? How can I avoid / correct it?
2. How could I make the axis to start at 0 rather than the somewhat arbitrary number that is being defaulted to.

```
    plots3=(ggplot(iris2l1)         # defining what data to use
    aes(x='Month', y='Redoc Proportion',  fill='Year')    # defining what variable to use
    geom_col(stat='identity', position='dodge') # defining the type of plot to use
    theme(axis_text_x = element_text(angle=90))
    labs(title="Redocumentation Proportion)
    theme_grey(base_family = "Helvetica")
    theme(figure_size=(8, 6))
```

[A plot created using Plotnines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRACe.png)

Comment: Likely (speaking R ggplot2 experience, none with plotnine), your y-variable is a character/string/categorical, whereas I'd imagine it should be an integer/double/numeric type.

Comment: This solved the problem. TY!